# why push notification display in json format in objective c ? I want string Format?

Tags: json

Json Format:

```
{aps ={alert="{\"NotificationTypeId\":3,\"Message\":\"   
    {\\\”User_Id\\\":1,\\\"PollsQuestion_Id\\\":186,\\\"PollQuestion\\\":
    \\ \"HELLO ANSWER THIS  POLL\\\",\\\"polloptionsdetails\\\":  
    [{\\\"Pollsoptio";badge = 3;sound = "sound.caf";};}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Pasting code is not acceptable in Stackoverflow. Please explain the problem in words, add the code in a proper way and focus your question.

Comment: When ever the server people send a notification, that time notification coming above format why?

Comment: Because that is how apple implemented it, you have no choice but to adapt and do any conversion yourself